# How to set session configuration in example CNN Estimator for MNIST (built with tf.layers)

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and learning about how to implement CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks). I am using this [official example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py)). When I try to run it on GPU it gives **cuda_error_out_of_memory**, as it tries to allocate the entire GPU memory available. I ran it on CPU by setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" environment variable and it worked fine but took lot of time.

I looked for solution to cuda_error_out_of_memory and found it can be mitigated by setting `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` or `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction =` in the tf session.

**Question:** In the code I shared above for CNN where do I set the session configuration as I don't see any `session.run()` type of command. I assume its being called internally in the layer methods. So, where do it set it? Is there any way I can set session configuration globally for one file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any configuration in the Estimator's constructor:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model", session_config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
  sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)

  run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(session_config = sess_config)
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model", config=run_config)
```

Add this code before creating Esitimator.